# hyperledger fabric - certificate renewal

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I renewed the certificates of peer msp, orderer msp and tls. I am able to query the data from the ledger. But when I try to invoke the data, I got the following error,

Error: error sending transaction for invoke: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- channel renewalchannel is not serviced by me.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this? If I missed anything?

Comment: the peer from which you are trying to invoke the transaction, have that peer joined channel "renewalchannel"?

Comment: Yes it is joined. It has two organizations each with one peer node. Both the peer nodes are joined in the renewalchannel. Before cert expiry, I was able to perform invoke and query. After cert renewal, I can only able to query the ledger. During invoke transactions, I got the above mentioned error. After cert renewal, I just restarted the peer, peercli, orderer. If I missed anything?